# Is this warning alright - "#368-D: <entity> defines no constructor to initialize the following:"?

Tags: c++, constructor, compiler-warnings

In my C++ code, I have a const array of objects of a struct type. This structure has some const members.

My hardware compiler (GHS Multi2000) throw the warning:

> warning#368-D: class defines no constructor to initialize the following:

Is this warning alright?
I read online that this can be ignored. It is simply that the compiler expects const members to be initialized in the constructor initialization list. Can this warning be suppressed?

Answer (score 1):

The warning is all right, and meaningful. What value do you expect these `const` members to have, without an initializer? So why not remove them then?